# How can I stop Adobe Flash from crashing

Tags: adobe

After switching to Ubuntu 12.04, Adobe Flash crashes every time I try to share my video. What can I do? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Adobe Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the proprietary drivers? Have you tried different browsers? If you're not happy with Adobe Flash, there are some alternatives:

> They are Gnash and Lightspark. (Another is Swfdec though development is almost stopped. In 2009, only 9 commits were made in the git repository).

Lightspark is available from the project's Launchpad page: https://launchpad.net/lightspark.

Installation of LightSpark

Press Ctrl+Alt+T and run the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sparkers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install lightspark browser-plugin-lightspark
```

Gnash and Swfdec are available as Ubuntu packages from the Universe repository.

Gnash can be installed by downloading the `mozilla-plugin-gnash` package.

Instalation of Gnash

Open a terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T) and run:

```
sudo apt-get install gnash mozilla-plugin-gnash
```

> Swfdec can be installed by downloading the swfdec-mozilla package.

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/Flash)